# UWP App with BackgroundTask won't build anymore Error 80080204

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have a UWP app that doesn't seem to build now. What's odd is I have another project that's very similar to it, but it builds just fine. The background task isn't an audio bg task. What is suddenly causing this?

> Validation error. error 80080204: App manifest validation error: Line
>   43, Column 12, Reason: If it is not an audio background task, it is
>   not allowed to have EntryPoint="App.TokenRefreshBackgroundTask"
>   without ActivatableClassId in
>   windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer.

Targeting build 18362.

Comment: Could you build the project successfully in lower version such as 17763? if possible provide [mcve]?

Comment: It's so weird. Changing the EntryPoint text/value and matching details on the background task project allows it to build for certain values and fails with the error for different values.

Comment: Do you mean that you have found the issue point ? *EntryPoint text/value does not match*

Comment: No. There's still something not right about it. I at least know that different values for `EntryPoint` produces the error. I will try to change target to 17763, too.

Comment: Could you share a repro simple sample for us that  I could find the issue point quickly ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194923/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-carlo-mendoza).

Comment: Please check your Task project properties(right click project -> properties-> Library). Pleas make sure the  Assembly Name and default namespace is same as project name after modified

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

It turns out this behavior is by design. 'Async' background tasks are not supported by the platform.

--

**Old answer, for completeness**

It turns out this is a bug in how the AppxManifest is generated during a packaging build.
I've filed a bug to address this and will update this thread and the Developer Community ticket once I have an update on its availability.

For now, you can get around this issue by manually specifying the inProcServer entry as a global Extension, like so:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
   <InProcessServer>
    <Path>CLRHost.dll</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="App.TokenRefreshBackgroundTask" ThreadingModel="both" />
   </InProcessServer>
  </Extension> 
</Extensions>
```

Where ActivatableClassId must match the EntryPoint of the backgroundTasks extension.

**Note** that this is NOT the same 'Extensions' block as the one under the 'Application' node. This one lives at the 'Package' level as a peer of the 'Applications' and 'Capabilities' nodes.

Comment: It's interesting that removing `async` works around the issue. Thanks for providing the more correct workaround. Looking forward to the fix!

Comment: I wonder why [Microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) says it can be _async_. Maybe it's outdated?

Comment: I agree with @skst, running async Background tasks is almost essential in many cases, and should be allowed according to the documentation. Is there a way to avoid this?
I'd be interested where you got this information from, cause this doesn't sound correct at all

Answer (score 2):

The line `public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)` cannot be `async`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

namespace BackgroundTask
{
    public sealed class TokenRefreshBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) says it can be _async_. Maybe it's outdated?

Comment: So why has this worked for years, and now is suddenly not supported? I'm interested in knowing which version I should roll back to

Answer (score 0):

I also hit this error when I forgot to add the RunTimeComponent project that implemented the IBackgroundTask class as a reference in the UWP project.